# What is the best way to add a class to a component based in a input property?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a custom button component and based in a property, i need to add a specific class, example:

```
<mybutton primary>Primary button</mybutton>
```

Needs to add to this component this class:

```
.primary {
   background-color: green;
}
```

I'm looking for any idea or tutorial of how i can make this

Comment: interesting thing but looks impossible approach. you can just define an input property like `color` and pass the value to it? like `<mybutton color="primary">`

Comment: yes, i think that this way can do what i need, you can make a example of how i can take this value in my component and apply a class? Example: i will have: primary, secondary and danger, i'm looking for a organized way to decide wich class this will be add to this element

Comment: Pass the class name as @input to that component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you need to set the class on your component host element

Add below to your `mybutton` component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

...

@Input()
@HostBinding('class')
color = "primary"
```

This will accept a value through `color` input and set the component's host element's class as the value passed. (default value is primary)

2. When you need to set the class on an element inside your component

```js
@Input()
color = 'primary';
```

```html
<button [ngClass]="color">
   <ng-content></ng-content>
</button>
```

This will pass a class name through `color` input and set the `button` element's class via `ngClass`.

**Note**:

Also if you want to display the text between your component selectors(for example, `Primary button` in your question), you have to add:

```html
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

in your `mybutton` component html.

**Demo**:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-attributes

Answer (score 1):

Add a input property className in mybutton and pass the value.

```
@Input() className: string;
```

And bind the value in your mybutton template

<`div [class] ="className" >Some text</div>`